# How to do DB changes in DynamoDB during CI/CD pipeline deployment

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, continuous-deployment

Our application is Springboot App with DynamoDB as Database. Deployment is done by using AWS Code pipeline in ECS Fargate.

Need to know how can I make DB changes like creating new table, adding GSI on existing table, inserting app specific configurations in existing table,.. during new build deployment. So that there will be no manual intervention in the deployment.

Comment: you can use [cloudformation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) or [cdk](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) to manage infrastructure

Comment: You could use Flyway or Liquibase as well

Answer (score 0):

Just as Balu mentions, the proper way is to use apppropriate tooling suck as cloudformation or cdk, the Java sdk can also accomplish this though.